# Error with LOAD DATA with Mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I have an issue trying to insert data in a mysql data base from a csv. My script is as follow:

```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/michael/Documents/Data/converted_sourceA/EURUSD_MyData_60_20140801_20140831.csv'  
INTO TABLE DATA_OHLCV  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(@var1, open, high, low, close, volume)  
set date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%Y%m%d-%H%i%s.%f'),
set id_source = 'srcA',
set timeframe = 60,
set id_asset = 'EURUSD';
```

The error message is:

**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set id_source = 'srcA',
set timeframe = 60,
set id_asset = 'EURUSD'' at line 8**

I really don't see my error and its been a while I am looking for it. 
Can someone help me ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `SET`, you just need to put it once then delimit the fields with a comma:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/michael/Documents/Data/converted_sourceA/EURUSD_MyData_60_20140801_20140831.csv'  
INTO TABLE DATA_OHLCV  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(@var1, open, high, low, close, volume)  
set date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%Y%m%d-%H%i%s.%f'),
id_source = 'srcA',
 timeframe = 60,
id_asset = 'EURUSD';
```

Comment: I just noticed that. I spend hours while it was obvious. Thank you very much for your help